# Django is not rendering the Images in Development

Tags: python, django

I started learning Django recently and I am also new to Web development.
I am facing an issue with Django not loading images but loading CSS and JS files.
I have done the setup as shown in Django documentation and also referred to many youtube videos.
My setup is almost the same. But still images are not loading.
Below is the Pip freeze of my virtual environment

```
(venv) PS E:\django\myproject> pip freeze
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.8
pytz==2021.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

Below is my Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

```
HTML
{%for product in products %}
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'products/images/flour.png' %}" alt="No Image">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{product.product_name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{product.product_description | default:"Nothing"}}</p>
                <a href="/products/{{product.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
              </div>
            </div>
{%endfor%}
```

Folder Structure

```
myproject
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
products
  - static
     - Products
       - images 
         - flour.jpg
  - templates
      - base.html
      - **products.html** #Image is to be loaded in this page
  - models.py
  - urls.py
  - views.py
```

Error in console
[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7yoU.png)
Please let me know if anything more required
Thanks in advance

Below is the log from server

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 29, 2021 - 13:02:41
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
{'products': <QuerySet [<Product: 120010>]>}
[29/Oct/2021 13:02:45] "GET /products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1796
[29/Oct/2021 13:02:45] "GET /static/Products/styles/app.css HTTP/1.1" 200 40
[29/Oct/2021 13:02:45] "GET /static/products/scripts/app.js HTTP/1.1" 200 117
[29/Oct/2021 13:02:45] "GET /static/products/images/flour.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1935
```

Comment: please share the error in the browser console

Comment: Attached the console error

Comment: could you hover over that flour.png:1 on the right side of the console and tell the path it is looking at

Comment: Have you followed the instructions? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Also, make sure your character case is correct! Your "Folder Structure" has `Products` with an upper-case P and your path has `products` with a lower-case P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** Make sure you have the load static tag in the top of the html

**2** Try attaching this to your url ( to the main urls.py and also the apps urls just in case )

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

**#These two lines and the last line after square bracket**

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('homepage.urls') ),
    path('register/', include('registration.urls') ),    
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls') ),
    path('teams/', include('team.urls') ),
    path('matches/', include('match.urls') ),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hi Sangeeth, I didn't have MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT configured in my Settings.py file..

Comment: sorry ... forgot to change it

Comment: I has this setup already main urls.py file.. And also, flours.png is looking for path (https://127.0.0.1:8000/static/products/images/flour.png)

Comment: do you have the load staticfiles tag in your template ?

Comment: Yes.. I have used that tag in my file.. As i said, Javascript and Css are loading perfectly.. But for images i am getting error in console

Comment: check the path.. i believe it is case sensitive... in your settings " staticfiledirs "

Comment: below are the settings 
```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: revert back to the old STATICFILES_DIRS but only change the small 'p' to CAPITAL 'P' to match your file structure

Comment: Issue resolved, as you have explained, issue is with the path and also my image is of type jpg whereas in HTML it is mentioned as png

Comment: it doesn't resolve the problem for me, and Media folder (defined in the database model) is not naturally generated in the static folder

Comment: the only time images are working in html (with an url, not a path) is when the application is set to debug mode (Debug = True) in settings.py...Images stop working in development mode probably as a security feature...